# Formatting the time slot of a Pylon's deform.widget.DateTimeInputWidget

Tags: python, datetimepicker, pyramid, pylons, deform

##### Needs

I need to customize a [`deform.widget.DateTimeInputWidget`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/api.html#deform.widget.DateTimeInputWidget), especially to get rid of the seconds in the input time slot so that the user doesn't need to specify them. By default seconds have to be filled but I'm only interested in hours (24h based) and minutes.

[image]
*Default deform DateTimeInputWidget. How to get rid of those pesky seconds in the time slot?*

##### What I found

I was really attracted by the option called `time_options` in the doc, but it only says:

> time_options
> A dictionary of time options passed to pickadate.

without any example of such dictionary. This is apparently needed to feed this JavaScript code: https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/blob/master/lib/picker.time.js but I don't really know where and how by looking at this code.

Even more confusing is the fact that the default value ( `default_time_options`) which is hard coded is not a dictionary: https://github.com/Pylons/deform/blob/f4da7dffb0b9235babe4e99596eefd1a6170c640/deform/widget.py#L696  is a tuple of tuples, which is then converted into a dict: https://github.com/Pylons/deform/blob/f4da7dffb0b9235babe4e99596eefd1a6170c640/deform/widget.py#L737-L741

And from the example, this `(("format", "h:i A"), ("interval", 30))` is transformed into: `{'format': 'h:i A', 'interval': 30}`.

The thing I don't understand here is the format itself: `'h:i A'`. It's quite obscure to me as it doesn't seem to rely on any of the standard format for formatting a time string in Python (https://strftime.org/).

##### Question

Hence my question: how could I force the time part of the `deform.widget.DateTimeInputWidget` to be like: `%H:%M` ?

With `%H` = hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number and `%M` = Minute as a zero-padded decimal number, as described in: to https://strftime.org/

Or some format which would lead to the same output, e.g. 00:01, 06:15, 10:10, 18:00 or 23:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up at the right place:

https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/#formats

where one can see in the time picker documentation how it is build in JavaScript:

```js
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
  // Escape any “rule” characters with an exclamation mark (!).
  format: 'T!ime selected: h:i a',
  formatLabel: '<b>h</b>:i <!i>a</!i>',
  formatSubmit: 'HH:i',
  hiddenPrefix: 'prefix__',
  hiddenSuffix: '__suffix'
})
```

In addition with the quite "unusual" (I have never ever seen `i` for formatting  minutes before, neither `a` or `A` for the day period...) formatting rules: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/#formatting-rules

[image]

Same goes for the date picker if by any chances you are also interested in formatting dates: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#formatting-rules

[image]

Then from Python, you can set the `time_options` and/or the `date_options` in your [`deform.widget.DateTimeInputWidget`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/api.html#deform.widget.DateTimeInputWidget) as follow:

```py
time_options = {
    'format': 'HH:i',
    'formatLabel': 'HH:i',
}
```

or any other of the [format](https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/#formats) options as standard `key:value` pairs.

Same goes for the `date_options`, e.g.:

```py
date_options = {
    'format': 'dd-mm-yyyy',
}
```

Notice: in some situations, this may not be taken into account in a private browsing window (I don't know why, I simply noticed that).